# Laravel: Method Illuminate\Http\Request::validate does not exist in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 68

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

```
Laravel: v5.7.28
Voyager: v1.2.0
PHP: 7.2
Database: MySQL 8.0
```

I setup Voyager Admin Panel on my Laravel E-commerce.
When I try to login, I see an error:

> (1/1) BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Http\Request::validate
>   does not exist.

Stack:

```
--
in Macroable.php line 100
at Request->__call('validate', array(array('email' => 'required\|string', 'password' => 'required\|string')))in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 68
at VoyagerAuthController->validateLogin(object(Request))in VoyagerAuthController.php line 24
at VoyagerAuthController->postLogin(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VoyagerAuthController), 'postLogin'), array(object(Request)))in Controller.php line 54
at Controller->callAction('postLogin', array(object(Request)))in ControllerDispatcher.php line 45
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(VoyagerAuthController), 'postLogin')in Route.php line 219
at Route->runController()in Route.php line 176
at Route->run()in Router.php line 682
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 163
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 75
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 163
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 163
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in StartSession.php line 63
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 163
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 163
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in EncryptCookies.php line 66
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 163
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in Router.php line 684
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))in Router.php line 659
at Router->runRoute(object(Request), object(Route))in Router.php line 625
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))in Router.php line 614
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))in Kernel.php line 176
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in InjectDebugbar.php line 65
at InjectDebugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 163
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 62
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 163
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in Kernel.php line 151
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))in index.php line 55
```

Error in Laravel https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L67

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }
```

I check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation and it's correct code.
Please help, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Can you share your complete LoginController ?

Answer (score 1):

i don't proper reason for this but i faced same issue after update to 5.6.
Use

```
use Request;
```

instead of

```
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
$this->validate(); method and pass in $request as the first parameter

or, you can use the 
Validator::make(); method and pass in $request as the first parameter